Bedrock-protocol в termux
В общем, мне надо имитировать бота для Майнкрафт бедрок сервера, я решил использовать Bedrock-protocol но у меня возникли трудности, установил я его в домашнию директорию, но при запуске выдало это:
~/bedrock-bot $ node --trace-deprecation bot.js
(node:9791) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
    at node:punycode:3:9
    at BuiltinModule.compileForInternalLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:399:7)
    at BuiltinModule.compileForPublicLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:338:10)
    at loadBuiltinModule (node:internal/modules/helpers:112:7)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:17)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:219:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:12)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:138:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/url-state-machine.js:2:18)
Connecting to АЙПИ.aternos.me:15895 Test Https-get-post. (Test), version 1.20.50
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/protodef/src/compiler.js:405
      throw new Error('Unknown parametrizable type: ' + type[0])
            ^

Error: Unknown parametrizable type: bitflags
    at SizeOfCompiler.compileType (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/protodef/src/compiler.js:405:13)
    at SizeOfCompiler.generate (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/protodef/src/compiler.js:239:34)
    at ProtoDefCompiler.compileProtoDefSync (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/protodef/src/compiler.js:42:44)
    at createProtocol (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/bedrock-protocol/src/transforms/serializer.js:41:34)
    at createSerializer (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/bedrock-protocol/src/transforms/serializer.js:61:17)
    at Client.init (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/bedrock-protocol/src/client.js:44:23)
    at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/bedrock-protocol/src/createClient.js:28:16
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/node_modules/bedrock-protocol/src/createClient.js:29:28

Node.js v22.12.0
~/bedrock-bot $

А вот сам код bot.js:
const bedrock = require('bedrock-protocol');

const client = bedrock.createClient({
    host: 'АЙПИ.aternos.me', // IP сервера
    port: 15895,                  // Порт сервера
    username: 'TermuxBot',        // Имя бота
});

client.on('join', () => {
    console.log('Бот подключился к серверу!');
});

client.on('text', (packet) => {
    console.log(`[Чат] ${packet.source}: ${packet.message}`);
});

client.on('disconnect', (packet) => {
    console.log('Бот отключился:', packet.reason);
});

Что я делаю не так, подскажите.

https://github.com/PrismarineJS/bedrock-protocol/issues/559
